# Make a http call with axios in the nuxtServerInit action

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on a static website fetching content from the WordPress API.

On the menu of the website, I want the content to be save on a nuxt store, and available on the nav component.

I reed the doc of the nuxt server and the nuxtServerInit action, but I didn't find a nice example of how to make a axion call inside this action, and be able to fetch the store on the component.

> I find this, but it's not working .. https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2307

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You can use property asyncData for load content. Link https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/

Answer (score 9):

Try this

store/index.js

```
export const state = () => ({
  data: null
})

export const actions = {
  // nuxtServerInit is called by Nuxt.js before server-rendering every page
  async nuxtServerInit({ commit, dispatch }) {
    await dispatch('storeDispatchFunc')
  },

  // axios...
  async storeDispatchFunc({ commit }) {
    const { data } = await this.$axios.get('/api/wp....')
    commit('SET_DATA', data)
  },
}

export const mutations = {
  SET_DATA(state, theData) {
    state.data = theData
  }
}
```

Comment: upvoted! does this mean when you manually type the page number of your API in the url and do a query nuxtserverinit is called each time, how would you call it externally if you wanted to paginate servr side